# Laptop overheating, tried almost everything

Tags: overheating

I have a laptop HP Pavilion G4 1305au, from last month it is overheating and when I started monitoring temperature it reached to 99 degree Celsius. I applied thermal compound twice, cleaned vents, got an 90B error for fan so changed that, updated BIOS but still condition is same. I noticed that after starting laptop fan got off and temperature starts going up, when I unplugg the AC Adapter plug fan starts working again and temperature gets down for some time. I am sick of it now, don't know what to do. I just started learning coding by giving up my carrier in commerce so it's the only machine I have and can't afford purchasing much hardware.

PS: I am using Windows 7 without any visual effects.

Comment: So this laptop did not overheat when new?    This is a problem that has started recently?

Comment: It started recently.

Answer (score 0):

My stab in the dark is that it might be a broken thermistor either on your CPU or motherboard. Most likely CPU, so it might be dying. Sorry.

If unplugging the AC adaptor helps, then you might be able to change some settings in your BIOS to set fan speed to 100% and ignore any temp measurements. Look for anything related to fan speed in your BIOS. Look in a Power section or something similar. Low-end laptops motherboards may not have this functionality built into the BIOS though.

Failing all the above, download a program to control your fans through Windows, such as [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php). You'll have to run this in the background all the time, but you should be able to manually force some loud high-speed fan action, which will cool everything down.

Comment: In BIOS there was an option to set fan always on, It was already enabled, downloaded speedfan. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does SpeenFan allow you to cool the laptop down?

Comment: No, all I can do is monitor fan speed and see temperature, it is not allowing me to control fan speed.

Comment: Perhaps bios doesn't have any option to control fan speed that's why this software is not allowing me to control fan speed.